# Setting up Ogre Game Engine in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: software-installation, 16.10

What method would I use to install the Ogre Game Engine in Ubuntu 16.10? Would it be one of these three options

- `.deb` file
- `ppa`
- `wget`

or something else?

Comment: To install Ogre-1.9, you simply have to run `sudo apt-get install libogre-1.9-dev` from terminal.

Comment: The above code downloaded something I don,t know what it is, but it ain't Ogre

Comment: It downloads the libraries and development tools for Ogre 1.9.

Comment: You should check this link - http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Installing+the+Ogre+SDK?tikiversion=Linux

Comment: Ogre3D is *not* a game engine

Answer (score 0):

To install Ogre-1.9 in Ubuntu 16.10, follow the steps given below :-

1. To install Ogre3D libraries and development tools, run the commands given below(one-by-one) from terminal :-

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install libogre-1.9-dev`
2. Then follow this tutorial of [Setting Up An Application - Linux](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Linux) on **Ogre Wiki**